# Can you pass non-ascii characters to argv?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

Suppose you have a binary executable that accepts a command-line argument.

```
./process in
```

In this case, the input is: 'i' = 0x69, and 'n' = 0x6E

Is there anyway I could pass *specific bytes* as input, and not ASCII?

That is, I want to pass 0xF9.

0xF9 = 11111001

Note, there is no ASCII character (that I know of) that I can type onto the screen that would evaluate to 1111 1001 in binary (due to ASCII being limited to the range of 0-127).

But alas, I want this executable to receive the byte 0xF9 as input.

The executable is fixed; I don't have the source code for it, and I can't modify it.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, since the program arguments are nul-terminated strings.

Comment: A string is an array of characters. A character is a byte. I want there to be one character, and that byte to be "1111 1001". (followed, sure, by a null).

Comment: argv is an array of pointers to arrays of bytes, not ASCII characters. You can interpret these bytes anyway you want.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but in Windows console you can enter a character value by holding down the Alt key and typing its decimal value *on the key pad* in this case `249`.

Comment: If you use Bash as your shell, then `$’\xF9’` should pass the character (byte) to your program.  The only character (byte) that can’t appear within an argument is the null byte.  That strictly marks the end of the argument.

Comment: What makes you think you are using ASCII to being with? If you actually are, then, of course, the answer is, No. (As a start, see what `locale` (or `chcp` for Windows), say.)

Comment: You can write a C program that calls `execve` with whatever array you want, if you're having trouble with a shell.  But of course the strings will be treated as null-terminated by the kernel, so you can't pass data with embedded zero bytes.  You can pass an empty `argv`, though, so `argv[0]` is a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the MS-DOS days you could have entered `0xF9 = 11111001 = 249` with the key combination <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> typed on the keypad.

For Windows this still works like explained in [this article](https://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html).

For Linux/Unix you can use a similar approach using the key combination explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/197095/427002).